# Same test case but different output on codeblocks and Ideone

Tags: c++, tree

Ok, I have recently started attempting tree related problems, there is a simple code that finds the Height of a binary search tree. It works fine on my system on CodeBlocks, but gives different output (2 every time) when I compile it on online IDEs. For example On codeblocks

4

2 1 3 4

gives output 3

but on online IDEs(Ideone,Codechef, Hackerearth)

4

2 1 3 4

gives output 2

not only this test case, but all test cases give output 2 online. Please Help!!

the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    long value;
    struct node* right;
}tnode;
tnode* insertnode(long,tnode*);
tnode* createnode(long);
int height(tnode*);
void preorder(tnode*);
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    cin>>n;
    long input[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>input[i];
    }
    tnode *root=(tnode*)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
    root=NULL;
    //cout<<"HI"<<endl;
    root=insertnode(input[0],root);
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        insertnode(input[i],root);
    }
    //preorder(root);
    cout<<height(root)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
tnode* insertnode(long value,tnode* node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return createnode(value);
    }
    else if(value<node->value)
    {
        node->left=insertnode(value,node->left);
    }
    else if(value>node->value)
    {
        node->right=insertnode(value,node->right);
    }
}
tnode* createnode(long value)
{
    tnode* temp=(tnode*)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
    temp->value=value;
    temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
    return temp;
}
int height(tnode* node)
{
    int lht,rht;
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        lht=height(node->left);
        rht=height(node->right);
        if(lht>=rht)
        {
            return lht+1;
        }
        else
        {
            return rht+1;
        }
    }
}
void preorder(tnode* temp)
{
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
            cout<<temp->value<<" ";
            preorder(temp->left);
            preorder(temp->right);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance and sorry if i made any mistake in asking question.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`  and `typedef` with structs in C++?

Comment: `root = malloc(...); root = NULL;` is a memory leak.

Comment: `insertnode` doesn't return a value on all paths. Bug right there.

Comment: You really shouldn't do all that manual memory management - use smart pointers, containers etc. And for the love of $DEITY, at the *very least* use `new`/`delete` in C++, *NOT* `malloc`/`free` (but really just use containers and/or smart pointers). Ohh and don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr`. Also, `using namespace std;` is a really bad idea. As for `long input[n];`; standard C++ does not support variable length arrays, you are relying on a compiler extension - use `std::vector`.  That's just from a quick glance - this code has lots of serious issues.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is `insertnode`. It's declared to return a `tnode *`, but it doesn't always do so: It does `return createnode(value);` if `node` is `NULL`, but in all other cases it doesn't return a value. Your compiler should be complaining loudly about that.

Thus:

```
node->right=insertnode(value,node->right);
```

This line assigns a new node to `node->right` if it's `NULL` initially. But if it's not `NULL`, `node->right` gets overwritten with a garbage value.

---

Other issues:

- You have a memory leak here:

  ```
  tnode *root=(tnode*)malloc(sizeof(tnode));
  root=NULL;
  ```

  The pointer returned by `malloc` is lost as the second line overwrites it with `NULL`.
- There's no point in `typedef`ing struct types manually in C++. When you do `struct node { ... };`, you automatically get two names defined: `struct node` and `node`. No `typedef` required.
- Using `malloc` in C++ is not recommended. `new` (or `new []`) would be better; more better would be some sort of smart pointer; best would be some container type that handles memory management for you.